# Couldn't match type Integer in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

In the exercise that i'm doing for the Functional Programming course i'm asked to find the lowest x for which `x mod a = b`, being given a series of pairs `(a, b)`.

In the case when i'm given three pairs (tuples), i am using the following code:

```
solveModularEq :: [(Integer,Integer)] -> Integer
solveModularEq [(a),(b),(c)] = lowestModThree(fst(a) snd(a) fst(b) snd(b) fst(c) snd(c) 1)

lowestModThree :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> 
Integer -> Integer -> Integer 
lowestModThree a b c aa bb cc k
  | k `mod` a == aa && k `mod` b == bb && k `mod` c == cc = k
  | k > (aa * bb * cc) = aa * bb * cc
  | otherwise = lowestModThree a b c aa bb cc (k+1)
```

In the case that there is no such x, return the product of the moduli.

The errors i am getting are strange because it doesn't seem that i'm mismatching any types.

```
modEq.hs:3:32:
   Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’
              with actual type ‘Integer
                                 -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer’
   Probable cause: ‘lowestModThree’ is applied to too few arguments
  In the expression:
     lowestModThree (fst (a) snd (a) fst (b) snd (b) fst (c) snd (c) 1)
   In an equation for ‘solveModularEq’:
      solveModularEq [(a), (b), (c)]
         = lowestModThree
             (fst (a) snd (a) fst (b) snd (b) fst (c) snd (c) 1)

modEq.hs:3:51:
  Couldn't match type ‘Integer’
                  with ‘((a0, b0) -> b0)
                       -> (Integer, Integer)
                        -> ((a1, b1) -> a1)
                        -> (Integer, Integer)
                        -> ((a2, b2) -> b2)
                        -> (Integer, Integer)
                        -> ((a3, b3) -> a3)
                        -> (Integer, Integer)
                        -> ((a4, b4) -> b4)
                        -> (Integer, Integer)
                        -> Integer
                        -> Integer’
   Expected type: (((a0, b0) -> b0)
                   -> (Integer, Integer)
                   -> ((a1, b1) -> a1)
                   -> (Integer, Integer)
                   -> ((a2, b2) -> b2)
                   -> (Integer, Integer)
                   -> ((a3, b3) -> a3)
                   -> (Integer, Integer)
                   -> ((a4, b4) -> b4)
                   -> (Integer, Integer)
                   -> Integer
                   -> Integer,
                   Integer)
     Actual type: (Integer, Integer)
   In the first argument of ‘fst’, namely ‘(a)’
   In the first argument of ‘lowestModThree’, namely
     ‘(fst (a) snd (a) fst (b) snd (b) fst (c) snd (c) 1)’
```

Same happens in this implementation of mine of a recursive primality test implementation.

```
isPrimeRec :: Int -> Bool
isPrimeRec n = isPrimeRec'(isqrt(n) n)

isPrimeRec' :: Int -> Int -> Bool
isPrimeRec' divisor n
  | mod n divisor == 0 = isPrimeRec' (divisor-1) n
  | mod n divisor /= 0 = False
  | divisor < 2 = True
```

The error for this one is

```
palPrimes.hs:10:16:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘Int -> Bool’
    Probable cause: ‘isPrimeRec'’ is applied to too few arguments
    In the expression: isPrimeRec' (isqrt (n) n)
    In an equation for ‘isPrimeRec’:
        isPrimeRec n = isPrimeRec' (isqrt (n) n)

palPrimes.hs:10:28:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Int -> Int’ with actual type ‘Int’
    The function ‘isqrt’ is applied to two arguments,
    but its type ‘Int -> Int’ has only one
    In the first argument of ‘isPrimeRec'’, namely ‘(isqrt (n) n)’
    In the expression: isPrimeRec' (isqrt (n) n)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax to apply function `f` to argument `x` is `f x`, not `f(x)`. Applications associate left, so `f x y` means `(f x) y` -- that is, apply `f` to `x`, and apply the resulting function to `y`. If `x` is itself a complicated expression with function applications in it, you can use extra parentheses to disambiguate; so, for example:

- `a b c d` applies function `a` to arguments `b`, `c`, and `d`
- `a (b c) d` applies function `a` to arguments `b c` and `d`
- `a b (c d)` applies function `a` to arguments `b` and `c d`
- `a (b c d)` applies function `a` to a single argument, `b c d`

Comment: Changing `lowestModThree(fst(a) snd(a) fst(b) snd(b) fst(c) snd(c) 1)` to `lowestModThree (fst(a)) (snd(a)) (fst(b)) (snd(b)) (fst(c)) (snd(c)) 1` solved it for the first one, as noted by the user that commented (he deleted the comment).

Changing `isPrimeRec'(isqrt(n) n)` to `isPrimeRec' (isqrt n) n` fixed the problem for the second problem.

Comment: Now onto fixing the algorithm implementation correctness. Thank you.

Comment: Considering i don't have type mismatches anymore, solved.

Comment: @Cornul11 You should also change `lowestModThree (fst(a)) (snd(a)) (fst(b)) (snd(b)) (fst(c)) (snd(c)) 1` to `lowestModThree (fst a) (snd a) (fst b) (snd b) (fst c) (snd c) 1` for readability.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex, will do.